# How to find a PDE satisfying $\rho_{tt}=c^2(\rho_{rr}+2r^{-1}\rho_r)$ with $R=r\rho$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

I'm working on a course problem,

> In a compressible and uniform fluid the equilibrium density and pressure are $\rho_0$ and $p_0$, respectively. Due to the passage of a compressible perturbation, there are linear changes in density $\rho$ and pressure $p$, and the resulting fluid velocity is $u(x, t) = u(x, t)\textbf{i} + v(x, t)\textbf{j} + w (x, t)\textbf{k}$, where $u, v$ and $w$ are small.
>
> [... parts (i) and (ii) ...]
>
> (iii) In a particular case $\rho = \rho(r, t)$, where (as usual) $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$. By changing the variables from Cartesians to spherical polars show that $$\frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial t^2} = c^2\left(\frac{\partial^2\rho}{\partial r^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial r}\right). \tag{$\ast$}$$ Find the partial differential equation satisfied by $R = r \rho$, and hence write down the general solution of $(\ast)$. (You may quote d’Alembert’s general solution of the one-dimensional wave equation.)

I've done the "show that" but I'm not sure how to go about solving $(\ast)$. I sub in $\rho=Rr^{-1}$ and get
\begin{align}
(Rr^{-1})_{tt}
& = c^2R(r^{-1}_{rr}+2r^{-1}r^{-1}_r) \\
& = c^2R(2r^{-3}-2r^{-3}) \\
& = 0,
\end{align}
which doesn't seem useful. Could someone give me a pointer? I realise it'll be something to do with the d'Alembert solution.

Comment: What is $R$? A constant? A function?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Not specified. I assume it's a constant, namely a fixed value of $r$.

Comment: That doesn't make sense since $r$ appears I the formula for $R$. And it also doesn't make sense for constants to satisfy differential equations. You were most likely meant to treat it like a function. That means product rule.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yeah, that makes more sense now that you mention it. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: If $R = r \rho$ then $R$ _must_ be a function of $(r, t)$ as the RHS $r \rho$ is. Computing \begin{align} R_{t} &= r \rho_{t} \implies R_{tt} = r \rho_{tt} & \implies r^{-1} R_{tt} &= \rho_{tt} \\ R_{r} &= \rho + r \rho_{r} \implies R_{rr} = 2 \rho_{r} + r \rho_{rr} &\implies r^{-1} R_{rr} &= 2 r^{-1} \rho_{r} + \rho_{rr} \end{align} which simplifies the problem greatly.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thanks. Also first time I've seen align used in comments.